# covering the closed interval [0,1] infinitely many times

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm working on measure theory problem and I need to cover the interval $[0,1]$ with measurable sets $A_n$ with $m(A_n)=\frac{1}{n}$ infinitely many times. In my situation, $A_n = [0,\frac{1}{n}]$ is not useful because it does not cover infinitely many times (consider $n=1$). If it possible I want to obtain $\cup _{i=m}^{\infty} A_i = [0,1]$ for any positive integer $m$.

Comment: Hint: $A_1 = [0,1]$ covers $[0,1]$ once.  $A_2 = [0,1/2], A_3 = [1/2, 1/2 + 1/3], A_4 = [1-1/4, 1/4]$ covers it again. $A_5 = [0,1/5], A_6 = [1/5, 1/5 + 1/6], \ldots$